# Proof Idea: Convergence in Distribution to Constant => Convergence in Prob

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I wanted to ask if my proof to show convergence in distribution to a constant ==> convergence in probability is correct. It seems simpler than existing proofs I've found, so I wanted to verify its accuracy.

[image]

Comment: if the answer by user @geetha290krm below answers your question, it is best practice to accept it using the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

The third equality is wrong. In such proofs there is  a difference between $<$ and $\leq $. You should write $$P[c-\epsilon<X_n <c+\epsilon]$$ $$ \geq P[c-\epsilon<X_n \leq c+\epsilon/2]$$ $$=P[X_n \leq c+\epsilon/2]-P[X_n \leq c-\epsilon]$$ $$=F_n(c+\epsilon/2)-F_n(c-\epsilon]$$ $$ \to F(c+\epsilon/2)-F(c-\epsilon)=1$$ (since  $c - \epsilon$ and $c+\epsilon /2$ are continuity points of $F$).

Comment: Thank you very much! I also think that it should be >= in the second inequality.

Comment: @AryanDugar I have corrected the mistake.